# Install Ruby + Jekyll without root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, jekyll

I want to install Jekyll on my Linux system without root. These are steps I did:

Download and extract Ruby:

```
tar -xzvf ruby-XXX.tar.gz
cd ./ruby-XXX
```

Config and install from source:

```
./configure -prefix=/env
make
makeinstall
```

Export PATH:

```
export PATH=$HOME/env/bin/:$PATH
```

When I check `ruby -v` then it shows `ruby 2.5.5p157`, which seems correct.

However, when I install Jekyll with `gem install jekyll` then there is an error:

`mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/share/include/ruby.h`

So, it seems Jekyll can't find the local Ruby installation?

Comment: Do you have the `ruby-dev` package installed?

Comment: Yes, but I have to install it manually (without root). And Jekyll can't find the custom header path